# Disable hover on active link

Tags: hyperlink, hover, disable

I am trying to figure out how to not override the active link with the hover.

```
<style>
.primary-nav-wrapper nav a:active, .primary-nav-wrapper nav .active>a  {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #4F579D;}
.primary-nav-wrapper nav a:hover:not([active]) {border-bottom: 3px solid #DFE1E5;}
</style>
```

Comment: Could you provide your full code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your code, so I can't help you to the fullest, but I will try.

I think your CSS has a fundamental problem. I think you want this:

- On hover, give the `a` a grey border.
- If active, give the `a` a blue border.
- If somebody hovers and activates the `a`, it should **still be blue**.

If that is your problem, here is a working code:

```css
.primary-nav-wrapper nav a:hover  {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #DFE1E5;
}
    
.primary-nav-wrapper nav a:hover:active {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #4F579D;
}
```

```html
<div class="primary-nav-wrapper">
  <nav class="active">
    <a>test</a>
  </nav>
  <nav class="active">
    <a>test</a>
  </nav>
  <nav class="active">
    <a>test</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```